# Sort of double toolbar in an android project with drawer/fragment

Tags: android, toolbar

I do a android application but I have a problem. There is a second toolbar below the first one. I dont want to change the size/place from the bar with PrysonBeta on it, I just want to delete the bar below. (See picture)

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/19932552/28820275-b265e796-76b9-11e7-9d29-e64ae3a09a9d.png

Here is my code :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my main activity I'm using :

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

I often see people saying android:fitsSystemWindows="false" with true or false can fix it but it never did on my case.

Answer (score 1):

in your styles.xml try this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```